# Where cached data gets stored and how to query the data?

Tags: asp.net, linq, caching

I want to use ASP.NET caching. I have two questions:

1. Where is the cached data stored when ASP.NET caching is used? Is it stored server-side or client-side? If by default it is server-side, how does it helps in performance?
2. How to query the cached data? I have a lot of cached data and I want to retrieve records on the basis of filters. Do I have to use LINQ for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cached data is stored server side. It helps performance by keeping the cached data on the server in memory and easily accessible by the application. This performance improvement beats reading the data from files, database queries, etc.

The easiest way to "query" cached data is to reference the cached object by the key you cached it under, then treat it as it was when you first cached it. From this point, once your object is once again an object, you can reference the data as you see fit, optionally using LINQ or any other means that is appropriate from the cached object.

Comment: I want to query the cached data to retrieve only selected objects. What are the ways other than LINQ?